# How to start dynamic-dynamodb daemon

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

i cant get dynamic-dynamodb daemon running

```
$> dynamic-dynamodb
$>./dynamic-dynamodb -run  

2015-09-11 09:32:44,238 - dynamic-dynamodb - ERROR - Failed to connect to DynamoDB. Retrying in 5 seconds
2015-09-11 09:32:49,244 - dynamic-dynamodb - ERROR - Failed to connect to DynamoDB. Retrying in 5 seconds
2015-09-11 09:32:54,249 - dynamic-dynamodb - ERROR - Failed to connect to DynamoDB. Retrying in 5 seconds
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dynamic-dynamodb", line 22, in <module>
    import dynamic_dynamodb
  File "/root/dynamic-dynamodb/dynamic_dynamodb/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from dynamic_dynamodb.aws import dynamodb
  File "/root/dynamic-dynamodb/dynamic_dynamodb/aws/dynamodb.py", line 688, in <module>
    DYNAMODB_CONNECTION = __get_connection_dynamodb()
  File "/root/dynamic-dynamodb/dynamic_dynamodb/aws/dynamodb.py", line 616, in __get_connection_dynamodb
    time.sleep(5)
```

I have added IAM policy to my EC2

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
        "dynamodb:ListTables",
        "dynamodb:UpdateTable",
        "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "sns:Publish"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:sns:*::dynamic-dynamodb"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And if i do :

```
$> ./dynamic-dynamodb --run
```

I get no response and no changes has been made on my dynamodb table

What am i missing here !? What is the right way to start dynamic-dynamodb daemon ?
i got dynamic-dynamodb using pip not with CloudFormation template.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have dynamic_dynamodb installed on an EC2 server via pip.  Everything appears to be working so I will just give you the steps I followed in order to get it running as a daemon.

1. Install via pip
2. Create .conf file to house configuration parameters, I called mine dynamic_dynamodb.conf.  At the minimum you need the global section with aws-access-key-id, aws-secret-access-key-id, region, and check interval.  You also need the logging section with log-level and log-file I believe.  The only other thing you will need is at least one table section identifying the table you want to scale and how you want it to handle scaling for that table.  Check out the configuration options here [Configuration Options](http://dynamic-dynamodb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration_options.html)
3. Launch dynamic_dynamodb in daemon mode using `dynamic-dynamodb --daemon start -c dynamic_dynamodb.conf`  Depending on your enviroment you may need to alter the command to properly see files, in particular if you want to launch it from cron.